# Morningstar.com login using Python Requests

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to **log in to my Morningstar.com premium account** using the **requests module in python** as below. The post command runs through with status 200 but does not actually log me in.

(*When I download the balance sheet, I only receive the 5 year (non-premium) version instead of the requested 10 year (premium) version. This indicates that my login script fails, since the 5 year data is available without login. The balance sheet URL works correctly right when logging in manually in the browser.*)

Does anybody know **how to correctly set up the login script**?

It seems very straight forward but I have tried the whole day using different forms of the payload/ headers etc. and can't find the right way... Also, I am confused since I cannot find the Form Data information when inspecting the login page.

```
import csv
import requests

urlLogin = 'http://members.morningstar.com/memberservice/login.aspx'
urlBalanceSheet = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNYS:F&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&reportType=bs&period=12&dataType=A&order=desc&columnYear=10&rounding=1&view=raw&r=149906&denominatorView=raw&number=1'

payload = {
    "uEmail": "<userEmail>",
    "uPassword": "<userPW>",
    "remember_me": "on",
    "login": "Sign In"
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(urlLogin, data = payload)
    print(p.status_code)

    download = s.get(urlBalanceSheet)
```

Comment: It might be flagging requests as a bot and refusing. Try [`mechanize`](https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize), which is (mostly) indistinguishable from a browser.

Comment: looks like front end of morningstart is written in angular, when you send requests you will not get anything.  You need to use headless browser.

Comment: @Artyer What would the `mechanize` solution look like?

Comment: There is a great answer by @t.m.adam to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231042/778533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you can do to automate downloading from morningstar

pip install selenium
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html

install firefox, find out where your profile is here is an resource http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import requests
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


def timeme(method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        startTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        endTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

        print(endTime - startTime, 'ms')
        return result

    return wrapper

class Driver():
    def __init__(self,profile, diver_path, url):
        self.profile = profile
        self.driver_path = diver_path
        self.url = url

    def start_driver(self):
        user_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(self.profile)
        user_profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'text/csv')

        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=self.driver_path, firefox_profile=user_profile)
        driver.get(self.url)

        return driver

    def shutdown(self,driver):

        driver.quit()


@timeme
def login(driver, email = '', password = ''):

    wait_time = 1

    try:

        email_input = WebDriverWait(driver,wait_time).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="uim-uEmail-input"]')))


        email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uim-uEmail-input"]').send_keys(email)

        time.sleep(5) # wait time to see if you have input remove later
        pwd_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uim-uPassword-input"]').send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(5)
        sign_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uim-login-submit"]').click()



        title = driver.title
        driver.execute_script("window.open('http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNYS:F&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&reportType=bs&period=12&dataType=A&order=desc&columnYear=10&rounding=1&view=raw&r=149906&denominatorView=raw&number=1','new_window');") 
        time.sleep(1)

        return 0
    except Exception as e:

        return None

@timeme
def main():
    # i am using on my mac, if you are using windows change paths accordingly
    Mozilla  = Driver(profile = '/Users/yourname/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxxxxxxxxx.default',
           diver_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', # path to firefox driver
           url='https://www.morningstar.com/members/login.html?vurl=')

    driver = Mozilla.start_driver()
    download = login(driver, password='', email='')
    if download ==0:
       time.sleep(10) # let browser to download csv

       Mozilla.shutdown(driver) # shutdown 

main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is awesome! :-)

Comment: When I run this code, then it just starts the browser, and eventually I get the error message: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused` Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @usdn Did you ever get it to work? The above example does not work for me.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen How did you set up Driver()?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547598/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-connection-refused

Comment: @oshaiken Thanks for responding! I changed all paths for `Driver()`, but no luck. I ended up using this `requests` solution instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/48228778/778533