# How can I log in to morningstar.com without using a headless browser such as selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, get, python-requests

I read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17633072/111362) to the question:
"How to “log in” to a website using Python's Requests module?"

The answer reads:
"Firstly check the source of the login form to get three pieces of information - the url that the form posts to, and the name attributes of the username and password fields."

How can I see, what the name attributes for username and password are for this morningstar.com page?
https://www.morningstar.com/members/login.html

I have the following code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.morningstar.com/members/login.html'
url = 'http://beta.morningstar.com'

with open('morningstar.txt') as f:
    username, password = f.read().splitlines()

with requests.Session() as s:
    payload = login_data = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        }
    p = s.post(url, data=login_data)
    print(p.text)
```

But - among other things - it prints:

```
This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests.
```

What should `url` and `data` be for the `post`?

There is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44399294/778533), which makes use of `selenium`, but is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Morningstar.com login using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377692/morningstar-com-login-using-python-requests)

Comment: Yep, i don't know if it's possible with `requests`. It seems that a POST request is submited to `https://sso.morningstar.com/sso/json/msusers/authenticate` with the login data in `X-OpenAM` headers.

Comment: But i don't think it's a duplicate because the post you linked uses `selenium`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was kind of hard, i had to use an intercepting proxy, but here it is:

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
auth_url = 'https://sso.morningstar.com/sso/json/msusers/authenticate'
login_url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/api/v2/user/login'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

headers = {
    'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST',
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'content-type,x-openam-password,x-openam-username',
    'Origin': 'https://www.morningstar.com'
}
s.options(auth_url, headers=headers)

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.morningstar.com/members/login.html',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-OpenAM-Username': username,
    'X-OpenAM-Password': password,
    'Origin': 'https://www.morningstar.com',
}
s.post(auth_url, headers=headers)

data = {"productCode":"DOT_COM","rememberMe":False}
r = s.post(login_url, json=data)

print(s.cookies)
print(r.json())
```

By now you should have an authenticated session. You should see a bunch of cookies in `s.cookies` and some basic info about your account in `r.json()`.

---

The site changed the login mechanism (and probably their entire CMS), so the above code doesn't work any more. The new login process involves one POST and one PATCH request to `/umapi/v1/sessions`, then a GET request to `/umapi/v1/users`.

```
import requests

sessions_url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/umapi/v1/sessions'
users_url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/umapi/v1/users'

userName = 'my email'
password = 'my pwd'
data = {'userName':userName,'password':password}

with requests.session() as s:
    r = s.post(sessions_url, json=data)
    # The response should be 200 if creds are valid, 401 if not
    assert r.status_code == 200
    s.patch(sessions_url)
    r = s.get(users_url)
    #print(r.json()) # contains account details
```

The URLs and other required values, such as POST data, can be obtained from the developer console (Ctrl+Shift+I) of a web-browser, under the Network tab.

Comment: It works! Afterwards one can do `r = s.get('some other morningstar url')`, while logged in. You didn't answer my question as stated, but you answered my real question. I feel so dumb, when I read great answers like these. Thank you so much!

Comment: How could I have come up with this answer myself?

Comment: Usually you'd have to monitor the network traffic in your browser (Inspect > Network), but in this case you'll need an intercepting proxy or wireshark or similar tools, because of many requests / redirects. In my code you'll notice three requests, 1 OPTIONS, 2 POST. This was really challenging for me too!

Comment: It seems this guy is having the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103517/morningstar-with-python-requests-to-get-10-year-financial-data

Comment: It seems they changed their CMS, so I had to update the code. Note the the new content is dynamic, so it may not be easy to scrape it with Requests.

Answer (score 1):

As seen the code, the username input field is:

```
<input id="uim-uEmail-input" name="uEmail" placeholder="E-mail Address" data-msat="formField-inputemailuEmail-login" type="email">
```

the password input field is:

```
<input id="uim-uPassword-input" name="uPassword" placeholder="Password" data-msat="formField-inputpassworduPassword-login" type="password">
```

The name is listed for both in each line after `name=`:

Username: `"uEmail"`
Password: `"uPassword"`

Comment: Ahhh, yes. I used `Inspect` in Google Chrome, and it showed up. I couldn't see it, when looking at the page source. It answers my question, but I still can't log in. Do you mind, if I wait a second, before I accept your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @tommy.carstensen no problem! Glad to help!

Comment: Your answer was correct for my original question as stated, but the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231042/778533 answers my real question, and I will choose his answer as the correct one. But thank you for answering the original version of the question as worded, prior to me editing it. Thanks!