# selenium firefox Unable to locate window

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, ssh, geckodriver

I am using ssh connection to server and I'm unable to locate window using selenium3.4 and firefox56.
couldn't find a solution, noticed it's mostly an IE bug with selenium
code:
i

```
mport bs4 as bs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import re
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display


def get_soup(url):
    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')


def get_driver_soup(url):
    # driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox('/var/gecodriver19-64')
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "product-image-wrapper"))
        )
    finally:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        time.sleep(randint(30, 70))
        driver.quit()
        return soup
```

Complete Traceback::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jomashop.py", line 86, in <module>
    soup = get_driver_soup(companies_list[x] + page_suffix)
  File "jomashop.py", line 32, in get_driver_soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 587, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to locate window
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback..

Comment: where is it located?

Comment: Yes so we can see the line where the error is occurring..

Comment: Normally it's taking to long for the page to load.  Or sometimes your ip address can be banned if you make to many calls

Comment: added traceback. I don't think this is the issue because i've worked with that site before

Comment: Maybe there is extra traffic today.. try a high value wait like 100. To check

Comment: but are you sure it's not an issue with my code? have you seen the 'nowindowexception' before?

Comment: Yes I have seen the error and it is normally from timing out.. Looking at your code though. the error is in the BeautifulSoup Line.. I have provided a possible answer for you

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it is timing out when you try to use Selenium Driver to return the source HTML.

Instead of this:

```
finally:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
```

Try using requests instead:

```
import requests

finally:
    r = requests.get(url) 
    html_bytes = r.text 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_bytes, 'lxml')
```

This should pull only the html

Comment: returns :selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused

Comment: That means the server is blocking your IP , at a guess.. The code I posted does not use Selenium so that error is more than likely from the ......WebDriverWait(driver, 20)..... line..

Comment: have a look here.. maybe this is relevent.. ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547598/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-connection-refused

Comment: WebDriverWait is correct, worked locally. Stopped working on ssh

Comment: I think it will be the remote server.. sometimes they can ban you for like 30 mins.. sometimes permanent.. you really need to try the script on a completley different website to be sure its not the server

Answer (score 0):

Check your geckodriver.log file (should be in the same directory as python file)

If it says

```
Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays
```

then install pyvirtualdisplay:

```
 pip install pyvirtualdisplay selenium
```

You might need xvfb too:

```
 sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Then try adding this code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
```

Full example:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.python.org')

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to locate window
```

Change the line :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox('/var/gecodriver19-64')
```

To :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/var/gecodriver19-64/geckodriver')
```